# Device Administrator Add screen not appear

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm following [this kotlin example](https://developer.android.com/work/device-management-policy#kotlin) from google website to prompt user to grant Admin access right to my app, but for some reason, the screen does not appear. In OnActivityResult, the result is registered as cancelled. I don't know what I'm doing wrong but I appreciate if anyone could point me to the right direction :

```
    //this code resides in OnCreate method of current activity
    val compName = ComponentName(this, CurrentActivity::class.java)
    val adminActive = devicePolicyManager!!.isAdminActive(compName)

    if (!adminActive) {
        val intent = Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN)

        intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, compName)
        intent.putExtra(
            DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION,
            "......."
        )
        startActivityForResult(intent, PERMISSION_ADMIN_RIGHT)
    }


    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        when (requestCode) {
        PERMISSION_ADMIN_RIGHT -> if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) { // 
            Toast.makeText(
                this@CurrentActivity,
                R.string.WARNING_ADMIN_REQUEST_REFUSE,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show()
        }
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
}
```

API 28
Testing Device : Galaxy S6